# Firebase observeSingleEvent not triggering Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an ios app that integrates with Google Firebase using Swift. However, for some reason the observeSingleEvent is not triggering. From my understanding this should be called once and then stop. Below is the code:

```
var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("Officers").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
    })

}
```

For this I am just trying to print the snapshot to assure it is working.

**EDIT**

Here is my database structure

https://image.ibb.co/eDyCXv/Capture.jpg

Comment: Can you post your database structure?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that to the original question. I edited the question to include the database structure.

Comment: Do you have a valid internet connection on the device your testing, to retrieve the results?

Comment: When you say it's not triggering, do you mean you inserted a breakpoint inside the closure but it wasn't triggered?

Comment: I just tested the code myself and it worked. At first I realized I had forgotten to give read permission so I had to go back and change that. Is reading from that database reference authorized for the client?

Comment: I just got the opportunity to run it on a physical device and it worked. For some reason it is not working in the simulator for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not working in the simulator. Got it working on a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
})
```